# How to access internal method from Business layer

Tags: asp.net

I want to access the internal method how to access pleas help
    Business layer class

```
internal DataTable SaveCustomerDetail() {
    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[7];
    parameters[0] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@CustomerName", CustomerName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    parameters[1] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@CustomerEmailID", CustomerEmailIDl, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    parameters[2] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@CustomerPhoneNumber",CustomerPhoneNumber, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    parameters[3] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@CustomerAddress", CustomerAddress, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    parameters[4] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@TotalProducts", totalproducats, SqlDbType.Int, 100);
    parameters[5] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@TotalPrice", totalprice, SqlDbType.Int, 100);
    parameters[6] = DataAccesLayer.Addparameters("@PaymentMethod", PaymentMethod, SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    DataTable dt = DataAccesLayer.ExecuteDTBbyprocedure("SP_SAVECUSTOMERDETAIL",parameters);
    return dt;
}
```

This .cs where i want to acces the internal Method method:

```
protected void btnplaceorder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string productsid = string.Empty;
    DataTable dt;
    if (Session["Mycart"] != null) {
        dt = (DataTable)Session["Mycart"];
        BussinessLayer B = new BussinessLayer()
        {
            CustomerName = txtcustomername.Text,
            CustomerEmailIDl = txtcustomeremailid.Text,
            CustomerAddress = txtcustomeraddress.Text,
            CustomerPhoneNumber = txtphoneno.Text,
            totalproducats = Convert.ToInt32(txttotalproducts.Text),
            totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(txttotalprice.Text),
            PaymentMethod = rblpaymentmode.SelectedItem.Text
        };
        DataTable dtResult = B.SaveCustomerDetail();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Error 1 'BussinessLayer' does not contain a definition for 'SaveCustomerDetail' and no extension method 'SaveCustomerDetail' accepting a first argument of type 'BussinessLayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) its showing above error

Comment: Are they in the same `namespace`?

Comment: yes they are in same namespace

Answer (score 0):

Make the method `public`, like `public DataTable SaveCustomerDetail`, this is the simplest way.

If your application is designed on a View - ViewModel - Model pattern, as it seems, the business layer you are trying to access is located in a different assembly than your presentation layer. This means they are located in different `dll`'s (projects).

So what you are trying to do is to access the `internal DataTable SaveCustomerDetail` from another `dll`, which is not ok. You can only access a `public` method from another `dll`.

You can think of it this way: your event `btnplaceorder_Click` is part of a control in a presentation layer, while your `internal` method `DataTable SaveCustomerDetail` is part of the business layer. `btnplaceorder_Click`just does not know that there is a method called `DataTable SaveCustomerDetail` in your code, because you made it `internal`. So to make it visible to everyone who wants to call it, no matter where in your code, just make it `public`.

You can read more on differences between `internal` - `protected` - `public` here: [internal vs public in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182015/internal-vs-public-in-c-sharp).

And maybe it will help you to know about the View Model design pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=view+model+pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972094/how-to-access-internal-method                                 this is further explatnation