# Inconsistent accessibility in interface due to internal keyword

Tags: c#-4.0, interface

By default, a Class, an Interface and struct are 
internal in c#. Then why I am not able to access 
that same interface wherein I am passing it as a 
parameter to a constructor of a class within the same class file?
The solution to mark interface as public is true but then
whats the use of the by default nature of interface which is internal?

```
     // Did not mark as public
     interface IGetData
    {
        string ProvideData(int id);
    }

    public class EmpClientLogic
    {
        IGetData _getData;

        // Error on this line (if interface is not marked as public)
        public EmpClientLogic(IGetData getData)
        {
            _getData = getData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [internal vs public in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182015/internal-vs-public-in-c-sharp)